# Cannot install snips-nlu on Raspberry Pi: Can not find Rust compiler

Tags: python-3.x, rust, setuptools, snips

I followed [these instructions](https://snips-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) to install snips-nlu on a Raspberry Pi:

1. Rust Installation: `curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh`
2. Setuptools-rust:   `sudo python3 -m pip install setuptools-rust`
3. NLU Installation:  `sudo python3 -m pip install snips-nlu`

My console log:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: snips-nlu-utils, snips-nlu-parsers
.
.
.  error: Can not find Rust compiler
```

I tried with different Python versions.

I found [setuptools-rust](https://github.com/PyO3/setuptools-rust), but it did not help, because I don't understand what I should do with it.

How can I fix this Rust compiler error message and install snips-nlu on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: You've done as `rustup` tells you to for the first use and `source ~/.cargo/env`, right?

Comment: I hope, I understood you corecctly! I executed at first curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh; After that I have source ~/.cargo/env executed. And after that sudo python3 -m pip install setuptools-rust

Answer (score 0):

After install Rust compiler:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

You can try a restart and then continue the installation of NLU. 
Restart is to ensure that path of Rust is being recorded in PATH.